# How to display <IPython.core.display.HTML object>?

Tags: python, pycharm, fast-ai

I try to run the below codes but I have a problem in showing the results.
also, I use pycharm IDE.

```
from fastai.text import *

data = pd.read_csv("data_elonmusk.csv",  encoding='latin1')
data.head()

data = (TextList.from_df(data, cols='Tweet')
                .split_by_rand_pct(0.1)
                .label_for_lm()
                .databunch(bs=48))

data.show_batch()
```

The output while I run the line "data.show_batch()" is:

```
IPython.core.display.HTML object
```

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title. Instead add an answer to the question, then mark that answer as "accepted". That effectively marks the problem as solved.

Comment: Alternatively, simply delete your question if it's not going to help future visitors.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Yes, I just run these codes on jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by running the codes on Jupiter Notebook.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't want to work within a Jupyter Notebook you can save `data` as an HTML file and open it in a browser.

```
with open("data.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Comment: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not HTML

Comment: if you have HTML object obj, you should write obj.data, not obj

Answer (score 4):

You can only render HTML in a browser and **not in a Python console/editor environment**.

Hence it works in Jupiter notebook, Jupyter Lab, etc.

At best you call  .data to see HTML, but again **it will not render**.

Answer (score 2):

You could add this code after `data.show_batch()`:

`plt.show()`

Answer (score 2):

Just use the data component of HTML Object.

```
with open("data.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(data.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides writing it do a file is to use an HTML parser in Python to programatically edit the HTML. The most commonly used tool in Python is beautifulsoup. You can install it via

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

Then in your program you could do

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_string = data.show_batch().data
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
# do some manipulation to the parsed HTML object
# then do whatever else you want with the object
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm guessing your true question here is

Why does **The pycharm IDE** does not render html correctly

After a few tests, it seems that the PyCharm rendering does not support some html tags. The following work correctly:

```
display(HTML('<section><h1>Hello</h1><p>Text</p></section>'))
```

[image: Valid case where html is rendered]

But the following will output `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`

```
display(HTML('<table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>'))
```

[image: Invalid case, html is not rendered]

So the reason you are getting this result is because the HTML rendered contains some tags unsupported by PyCharm. Your workaround of using a real notebook is the correct thing to do, but I encourage you to open a bug to Jetbrains : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html